# Why does Eclipse warn about Java "unused variables" but javac does not?

Tags: java, eclipse, javac

For the same code, Eclipse shows warnings about unused variables, but compiling with "javac" (v1.6) does not. Does Eclipse use a different compiler or parser? How can I get javac to show the same warnings?

Comment: Because Eclipse works extra hard to be smart and helpful?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Quote from [JDT core](http://www.eclipse.org/jdt/core/) (Eclipse's editor infrastructure)

> JDT Core is the Java infrastructure of the Java IDE. It includes:
>
> *An incremental Java compiler*. Implemented as an Eclipse builder, it is based on technology evolved from VisualAge for Java compiler. In
> particular, it allows to run and debug code which still contains
> unresolved errors.

It is the incremental Java compiler that shows the warning.

There are no ways to enable that warning in Sun/Oracle `javac`

Answer (score 6):

Eclipse uses its own compiler.  You can enable/disable various messages by going to Window->Preferences->Java->Compiler->Errors/Warnings.

Comment: This does not answer my question. I want to enable the same warnings in javac.

Answer (score 3):

From [javadoc:](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/solaris/javac.html)

**-Xlint**
Enable all recommended warnings. In this release, all available warnings are recommended.

And yes, eclispe use own compiler

Comment: `-Xlint` does not have an option to show unused variable warning - I guess.

Comment: I just tried javac -Xlint foo.jar, and it doesn't show unused variables.

Answer (score 2):

This is Eclipse own functionality.

Answer (score 2):

This is part of the validation in eclipse.  If you wanted your own rules similar to what eclipse does, you could use something like PMD.

http://pmd.sourceforge.net/rules/unusedcode.html